# How can i pass 2 objects as return from json

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to bind 2 dropdown `City` and `Currency` based on the country selected. So I used Json and passed the selected countryId and wrote in the controller for getting corresponding currency and city values. But the problem is, how can I pass 2 values in json as return type?

Here is the code:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult BindCityAndCurrency(int CountryID)
    {
        var q = from r in db.Cities where r.CountryID == CountryID orderby r.CityID, r.CityName select r;

        var City = q.ToList().Select(c => new { Text = c.CityName, Value = c.CityID });
        var Currency = from items in db.Currencies where items.CountryID == CountryID orderby items.CurrencyName, items.CurrencyName select items;
        return Json(City,Currency);//here is the error showing Invalid Arguments I 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make it like this

```
return Json(new {city = City, curreny = Currency });
```

OR

```
 return Json(new {City, Currency})
```

Check the argument list in the helper method, it is not taking multiple data objects, you have to wrap those under on object and access on client side accordingly.

Please let me know if you required any help

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
return Json(new { City, Currency });
```